# Gecko(Firefox 3.6/4beta) Hides Div While Webkit(Chrome/Dreamweaver) Displays Just Fine

Tags: html, firefox, google-chrome, webkit, gecko

I've ran into a snag I've been working on for a couple days and can't seem to come up with an answer online.  The site template I'm working on now is located at "http://citylakersbaseball.org/2.0" - I've got a div named "sponsors" that shows up fine in Chrome and the built in Live View of Dreamweaver CS5 - however, in Firefox 3.6 & 4beta it completely vanishes.  I can see it in the view source, yet firebug has it grayed out.  Maybe it's a DOM issue? (for which I don't know much about).  Rendering engine issue?

I ran the source (index,htm) and CSS (style.css/nav.css) through the HTML validator - HTML is fine, and the CSS didn't spit back anything I would think could effect the div's display, especially since Webkit has no issues with it.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not showing for me in Google Chrome 8 as the css class `.sponsors` has `display: none !important` set

Comment: You should add a valid doctype like <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Answer (score 2):

Your ad-blocking Firefox plugin is detecting and removing the `div` from the DOM. I experienced the same behaviour in Chrome and Firefox (which have ad-blocking plugins/extensions), but not in Safari or IE (which don't); and, indeed, the `div` appears if I disable Adblock Plus. One of the more basic rules Adblock Plus and the like follow is to look for HTML elements with `class="sponsors"` or `id="sponsors"` and remove them.

Comment: Yep, that's why I'm not seeing it on my version of Chrome, I have AdBlock installed

Comment: Thanks Daniel.  One of those "right under my nose" issues.  Have a nice day!

Comment: Glad to help. I bet you spent like an hour trying to figure out what the heck was going on looking for help here, too... I know I've done that countless times! ;)